# Security has role vs is_granted

Tags: symfony

Could some explain to me the difference between : `@Security("has_role("ROLE_ADMIN")")` and  `@Security("is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")")`  and which one is more recommended?

Comment: has_role was depreciated in Symfony 4 and removed in Symfony 5.  So use is_granted.  They are identical when it comes to just checking for a user role.  However, the is_granted has the capability to check for specific permissions on specific objects.  There are still a couple references to has_role in the S5 docs.  Sooner or later they will get cleaned up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do the same job in that case, but the `has_role()` function in security expressions is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, so we should use `is_granted()` instead.

Comment: Official info: https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-2-curated-new-features#security

Answer (score 1):

I think that has_role() checks if the user already has the role. On the other hand, is_granted() runs the Voters to check if there is a role to be added to the existing roles.

Comment: This seems so overly-complicated and I'm glad they got rid of one. Having two ways to set or check a permission of a user on a thing based on what they are or what they're granted is confusing when talking with users or product owners or prospective clients about it. I don't know why they had two different ways to distinguish essentially the same thing.

Comment: It does serve in very specific scenarios, but for the most part, having just one is much less complicated.